# Adding newly created users to pre-existing groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

This script currently creates new users after importing data from a CSV file

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory    
Import-Csv "C:\testcsv.csv" | ForEach-Object {    
   $userPrincinpal = $_."samAccountName" + "@NWTC.local"    
   New-ADUser -Name $_.Name `    
              -Path $_."ParentOU" `    
              -SamAccountName  $_."samAccountName" `   
              -UserPrincipalName  $userPrincinpal `    
              -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "Password1" -AsPlainText -Force) `    
              -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false  `    
              -Enabled $true    
}
```

This is the csv file I am importing from:

```
Name,samAccountName,ParentOU,Group    
Test Test1,TTest1,"OU=Business,DC=NWTC,DC=local",TestGroup
```

After a user is created, I want to add them to an already exisiting group. There will be different groups I want different users to be added to, but only 1 group per person.

I've been playing around with `Add-AdGroupMember`, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Something like this: `Add-ADGroupMember -Members $_.Members`. This is the first time I'm working with CSVs, so I'm in new territory

Comment: What have you tried to add a new user to an existing group?

Comment: I've been playing around with Add-AdGroupMember, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Something like this: Add-ADGroupMember -Members $_.Members. This is the first time I'm working with csvs, so I'm in new territory

Comment: Did you take a look at this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps. You want to add member but you don't specify the AD group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`New-ADuser` does not support this functionality so you will have to do that yourself after the fact. What you *could* do is have `New-ADUser` spit out the AD user object it creates and use that with `Add-ADGroupMember`.

```
$newUserProperties = @{
    Name = $_.Name
    Path = $_."ParentOU"   
    SamAccountName = $_."samAccountName"   
    UserPrincipalName = $_."samAccountName" + "@NWTC.local"  
    AccountPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString "Password1" -AsPlainText -Force) 
    ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false  
    Enabled  = $true    
}

try{
    $newADUser = New-ADUser @newUserProperties -PassThru

    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.Group -Members $newADUser.SamAccountName
} catch {
    Write-Warning "Could not create $($newUserProperties.samaccountname)"
}
```

The error handling is crude but should exist in some form to account for failures in the source data or misconceptions of existing users. Basically just getting `$newADUser` and using it for `Add-ADGroupMember`

We use splatting of the parameters here. That way you don't have to worry about having nice formatted code by using backticks.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `Add-ADGroupMember` in the `ForEach-Object` after the new user is created :

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory    
Import-Csv "C:\testcsv.csv" | ForEach-Object {    
   $userPrincinpal = $_."samAccountName" + "@NWTC.local"    
   New-ADUser -Name $_.Name `    
              -Path $_."ParentOU" `    
              -SamAccountName  $_."samAccountName" `   
              -UserPrincipalName  $userPrincinpal `    
              -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "Password1" -AsPlainText -Force) `    
              -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false  `    
              -Enabled $true 

   Add-ADGroupMember -Identity 'AD_GROUP_WHERE_YOU_ADD_MEMBERS' -Members $_.samAccountName
}
```